# Logback Folder path issue

Tags: web8.5, logging

We are migrating from Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5

We are using ASP.NET In Process API Applications and use Tridion In Process API for Fetching data.
Each Application has its own config folder.

We are using PowerShell to Build Log folder path with respect to Application path
for example: Application1 folder path will be "D:\Live\Application1\Logging"

Instead of Tridion logs saving in "D:\Live\Application1\Logging"
It is creating under "D:\LiveApplication1Logging"

If we change above path to "D:/Live/Application1/Logging", Logs are saving in Given path.

Is it expected behavior or bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also seen this before and believe that it is expected behaviour (as the CD code is running in a JVM), but that it's just not documented very well.

As Paul Draper says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19762198/197993):

> Using forward slashes will make it system independent. I'd stick to that for simplicity.

However, as he also says, there are ways to allow either within the code, so this should either be documented or fixed. Given that the in-process approach is now deprecated, I wouldn't expect this to be rectified (so that it works with either type of slash).

Maybe a comment in the default config (xml) file would be the best place to document it?